# Parsing Nested JSON in java without know structure of JSON?

Tags: java, json, parsing, json-patch

I am Trying to parse nested JSON, But i don't know the format of JSON...I want all the Keys and Values of JSON.

Example:

```
{
    "txnSpecificData1": "11",
    "txnSpecificData2": "21",
    "merchantData": {
        "merchantSpecificData1": "111",
        "merchantSpecificData2": "222",
        "merchantSpecificData3": {
            "data1": "1",
            "data2": "2"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want all Keys and their Values...I tried JSONParser but it is not giving all keys.
Please some one guide me to do this.

I need value based on key..
Let's say If i give key as "merchantSpecificData2" it should return me value.

O/P should be MAP with all Key and Values:

```
OutPut Map : : : {txnSpecificData1=11, txnSpecificData1=22, merchantSpecificData1=111, merchantSpecificData2=222,data1=1,data2=2}
```

Comment: Your question is ill-formed. What result should asking for `"a"` from `{"a": 1, "b": {"a": 2}}` give?

Comment: @Eric I want all key with values store in a map.
txnSpecificData1:11
txnSpecificData2:21
merchantSpecificData1:111
merchantSpecificData2:222 
like wise

Comment: You've just ignored my question and restated yours even less clearly. Notice how in the "map" I gave above, the key "a" appears twice. Which value do you want, and why?

Comment: @Eric..In my case there is no duplicate keys..why are you asking me this?

Comment: You specifically said that you _"don't know the keys"_. So how do you know they're all unique?

Answer (score 3):

A iterative solution to store all keys and respective value into a map. Note,  all exception scenarios are not handled.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(your_json_String_here);
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    new Test().iterateJson(jo, map);
    System.out.println(map);
}
public void iterateJson(JSONObject jo, Map map) {
    for(Object o : jo.keySet()){
        if(jo.get(o.toString()) instanceof JSONObject) 
            iterateJson(jo.getJSONObject(o.toString()), map);
        else
            map.put(o.toString(), jo.get(o.toString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not suitable for my case

Comment: This example prints all the values of available keys in your JSON string as you requested. It is expected a bit modification if your requirement are little different, Please elaborate more where you stuck

Comment: I modified the code a bit, now it is populating a Map of all key value pairs and you can get value of any key using that map

Answer (score 2):

Please refer [this](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Sample Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String json = "{\"txnSpecificData1\": \"11\",\"txnSpecificData2\": \"21\",\"merchantData\": {\"merchantSpecificData1\": \"111\",\"merchantSpecificData2\": \"222\",\"merchantSpecificData3\": {\"data1\": \"1\",\"data2\": \"2\"}}}";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONObject merchantData = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("merchantData");
        System.out.println(merchantData.get("merchantSpecificData2"));
    }
```

**Output**

```
222
```

[Jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjettison13jar.htm)

[Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jettison/jettison/1.3.7)

[Refer hew for more details.](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/11/json-to-hashmap-parsing-json-string.html)

Comment: ...I have done this..but as i said i don't know the format..I mean instead of "merchantData" it can be anything

Comment: @user2888996 maybe using `Regex` looks weird but might solve

Comment: Okay...lF i use this only..then how can i find value for key "txnSpecificData1"

Comment: `jsonObject.get("txnSpecificData1");`, also you can always iterate recursivley the `jsonObject`, check for instance if it is array or object

Comment: @ ankur-singhal...I want all the keys to be stored in Map with their respective values..and i don't know any of the key also level of nesting

Comment: @user2888996 i got your point, answer edited, please click on link `Refer hew for more details.`, it will convert to `Map structure - key-value` pair

Comment: @ankur-songhal..i already tried this..i am getting this as MAP...now how can i find key here ???


{txnSpecificData2=21, merchantData={merchantSpecificData1=111, merchantSpecificData2=222, merchantSpecificData3={data1=1, data2=2}}, txnSpecificData1=11}

Comment: ...@help me ..I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/package-summary.html for parsing the JSON. Using JSONSerializer you can get a JSONObject parsing your string. Then methods available in JSONObject will give you all keys and values. Value can be simple like String/Long/Boolean or complex like another JSONObject/JSONArray.

Comment: ..This library i am not using also i am not getting how can i implement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution..

```
private static HashMap print(final JsonNode node) throws IOException {
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = node.getFields();

        while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
            final String key = field.getKey();

            final JsonNode value = field.getValue();
            if (value.isContainerNode()) {
                print(value);
            } else {
                map.put(key, value);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```